# Incomplete deletion of user account?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

While recently browsing old questions in Mathematics Meta, I came across a user with an undeleted [meta user account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/23452/gigili) but with a (seemingly) non-existent [main user account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23452/gigili).  I was under the impression that the creation of a meta user account requires the existence of a main user account.  This implies that the main user account was deleted after the meta user account was created.

> When a main user account is deleted, then shouldn't the associated meta user account also be deleted?

Comment: I later asked this question at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337939/361651).